# How can I make rails helpers more object-oriented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, helper

I'd like to, for all helpers, across my entire Rails application, replace this syntax:

```
time_ago_in_words(@from_time)
```

with this:

```
@from_time.time_ago_in_words
```

Ideally this change would also make the helpers available anywhere in my application (the same way, say, `5.times` is).

Does anyone know of a plugin that does this? Would it be difficult to roll my own?

Comment: Why is this important?  Perhaps some context would help...

Comment: I just find their existing syntax annoying and ugly. It would also be nice to call things like @post.truncate in my model (for caching, e.g.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a new model you can make it inherit the methods from an existing class.

Example (app/models/mykindofstring.rb):

```
class Mykindofstring < String

    def all_caps_and_reverse
        self.upcase.reverse
    end 

end
```

Then from the controller:

```
@my_string = Mykindofstring.new('This is my string')
```

and finally calling it from the view:

```
<%= @my_string %>
```

displays as This is my string, while:

```
<%= @my_string.all_caps_and_reverse %>
```

displays as GNIRTS YM SI SIHT.

The class inherits from the string class, so all the methods that apply to a string also apply to a mykindofstring object. The method in it is just a new name for a combination of two existing string methods, but you can make it do whatever you want, such as a method to convert a time into a formatted string.

Basically it's just extending a current Ruby class with your own methods instead of using functions/helpers.

**Major Edit**

Based on Ians comment to this answer and his own answer to the above question, I played around a bit in Rails and came up with adding this to the application_helper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  String.class_eval do
    def all_caps_and_reverse
      self.upcase.reverse
    end
  end
end
```

Now just call the method on any string in the app:

```
@string = 'This is a string.'
@string.all_caps_and_reverse
```

.gnirts a si sihT

Comment: But it's Ruby!  Subclassing is "proper" OO, but you don't want to create new objects of another type, you want to use actual God-given strings, so just open up the String class and add your method:  class String; def all_caps_and_reverse; self.upcase.reverse; end; end

Comment: Thanks, good point. I revised the answer accordingly.

Btw, this is why I like Stack Overflow; I've only been here a few days and my code is already improving.

Comment: Why do it with class_eval rather than just redeclaring the string class?

Comment: When inside the ApplicationHelper module, class_eval works. When outside, reopening the class works (I just did it in the same file, underneath the ApplicationHelper).

It's probably got something to do with defining a class inside a module. When doing some trial and error with it I had to restart the app, so it's may also have something to do with how Rails autoloads things.

I'm sure there are other places to put it and other ways to do it, but for a quick addition to the class it seems like better practice to use class_eval inside something that's already in the Rails load path.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find any easy way to do this across your whole application for all (or even most) helpers.

Helpers are structured as modules meant to be included in view rendering classes.  To leverage them, you'd have to keep a copy of an ActionView around (not a HUGE deal I suppose).

You can always open up the classes and specify each helper you want, though:

```
class Time
  def time_ago_in_words
    ActionView::Base.new.time_ago_in_words self
  end
end

>> t = Time.now
=> Tue May 12 10:54:07 -0400 2009
>> t.time_ago_in_words
=> "less than a minute"
(wait a minute)
>> t.time_ago_in_words
=> "1 minute"
```

If you take that approach, I recommend caching the instance of ActionView::Base that you use.  Or, if you don't want to go so heavyweight, you can create your own class to just include the helpers you want (you don't want to include the helpers directly in each Time, Date, String, etc, class, though, as that will clutter up the method namespace pretty fierce -- and conflict with the natural names you want).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ruby 2.1 you can use Refinements. They are an alternative to monkey-patching Ruby's classes. to borrow [@Jarrod's monkey-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851064/276959) example:

```
module MyString
  refine String do
    def all_caps_and_reverse
      upcase.reverse
    end
  end
end
```

You can now use this in any object you want:

```
class Post
  using MyString
end
@post.title.all_caps_and_reverse
```

You can [read more about Refinements](http://www.sitepoint.com/look-ruby-2-1/) here.

Answer (score 0):

Make a model, TimeAgo or something similar.  Implement following this idea here:
[a code snippet for "wordifying" numbers](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/447)

Then, in your controller, create the instance variables using this class.  Then, in your view, call `@from_time.in_words`